# Excluding Default Users with LDAP filter

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

```
0: "Exchange Online-ApplicationAccount"
1: "SystemMailbox{1f05a933-9ad6-4643-8c81-a99f111d5a14}"
2: "SystemMailbox{b3558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d5374122228c}"
3: "SystemMailbox{e2dc1c29-89c3-4034-b678-e6c29d823ed9}"
4: "DiscoverySearchMailbox {D919B115-46A6-415f-80AD-7E093333BB852}"
5: "Migration.8f3e7716-2011-43e4-9221-aba62d229136"
6: "FederatedEmail.4c1f4d8b-8179-4338-93bf-00a95fa1e042"
7: "SystemMailbox{D0E409A0-AF9B-4440-92FE-AAC869B0D201}"
8: "SystemMailbox{2CE34115-31BE-455D-89D7-A7C7DA7A0DAA}"
9: "SystemMailbox{8cc37553-822a-4ab8-a926-bb94bd0641a9}"
10: "Zeynep Demir"
11: "Mustafa Demir"
12: "Ali Demir"
13: "Ayse Demir"
14: "derya"
```

These are users when i query with ldap  via ("**(objectClass=User)**") but i want to filter first 10 record.

Is there a way to filter default users with ldap?

Comment: Look at the attributes using the Attribute Editor in AD Users and Computers and see if you can find an attribute that is common to only those. Then you can filter on that.

Comment: @GabrielLuci there is an attribute for filtering default groups (isCriticalSystemObject) but i'm not able to detect one for users.

Comment: If that attribute doesn't work for you, look for another one. Just look at all the attributes and find one that has a common value for all those accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all appear to be Microsoft-Exchange related accounts. They are created under the users container If all of your manually created accounts are under a separate single OU structure, you can restrict your search to a base. E.G. instead of searching at the base DN `cn=users,dc=example,dc=com` search at `ou=Company,dc=example,dc=com`

Alternately, use a not filter to remove accounts from the result set:

`(&(objectClass=user)(!(|(cn=DiscoverySearchMailbox*)(cn=ExchangeOnline-ApplicationAccount)(cn=FederatedEmail*)(cn=HealthMailbox*)(cn=Migration.*)(cn=SystemMailbox*))))`

Which means "find all objects where objectClass is user AND the CN is not (this or that or the other thing)".

A substring-based filter adds a little load to the directory server, but a new Exchange installation will add additional accounts. But the substring search avoids needing to modify the filter any time, for example, the set of SystemMailbox objects changes.